# jsp scriptlet to filter json doc

Tags: jsp, filter, stream, output

## I have the following result:

```
{
    "roles": [
        {
            "id": "9fe2ff9ee4384b1894a90878d3e92bab",
            "name": "_member_"
        },
        {
            "id": "427afafe637e42ee87b9c7603058dc57",
            "name": "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

===
which i get from an API call to Openstack. I need to filter it to get just the string: 427afafe637e42ee87b9c7603058dc57 ( in the second id ).

## Right now i have defined the following filter:

```
// One-liner to define JSON parser and stringifier.  Minified version of http://www.json.org/json2.js
if(!this.JSON){this.JSON={};}(function(){function f(n){return n<10?'0'+n:n;} if(typeof Date.prototype.toJSON!=='function'){Date.prototype.toJSON=function(key){return isFinite(this.valueOf())?this.getUTCFullYear()+'-'+ f(this.getUTCMonth()+1)+'-'+f(this.getUTCDate())+'T'+f(this.getUTCHours())+':'+f(this.getUTCMinutes())+':'+f(this.getUTCSeconds())+'Z':null;};String.prototype.toJSON=Number.prototype.toJSON=Boolean.prototype.toJSON=function(key){return this.valueOf();};} var cx=/[\u0000\u00ad\u0600-\u0604\u070f\u17b4\u17b5\u200c-\u200f\u2028-\u202f\u2060-\u206f\ufeff\ufff0-\uffff]/g,escapable=/[\\\"\x00-\x1f\x7f-\x9f\u00ad\u0600-\u0604\u070f\u17b4\u17b5\u200c-\u200f\u2028-\u202f\u2060-\u206f\ufeff\ufff0-\uffff]/g,gap,indent,meta={'\b':'\\b','\t':'\\t','\n':'\\n','\f':'\\f','\r':'\\r','"':'\\"','\\':'\\\\'},rep;function quote(string){escapable.lastIndex=0;return escapable.test(string)?'"'+string.replace(escapable,function(a){var c=meta[a];return typeof c==='string'?c:'\\u'+('0000'+a.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-4);})+'"':'"'+string+'"';} function str(key,holder){var i,k,v,length,mind=gap,partial,value=holder[key];if(value&&typeof value==='object'&&typeof value.toJSON==='function'){value=value.toJSON(key);}if(typeof rep==='function'){value=rep.call(holder,key,value);} switch(typeof value){case'string':return quote(value);case'number':return isFinite(value)?String(value):'null';case'boolean':case'null':return String(value);case'object':if(!value){return'null';}gap+=indent;partial=[];if(Object.prototype.toString.apply(value)==='[object Array]'){length=value.length;for(i=0;i<length;i+=1){partial[i]=str(i,value)||'null';} v=partial.length===0?'[]':gap?'[\n'+gap+partial.join(',\n'+gap)+'\n'+mind+']':'['+partial.join(',')+']';gap=mind;return v;}if(rep&&typeof rep==='object'){length=rep.length;for(i=0;i<length;i+=1){k=rep[i];if(typeof k==='string'){v=str(k,value);if(v){partial.push(quote(k)+(gap?': ':':')+v);}}}}else{for(k in value){if(Object.hasOwnProperty.call(value,k)){v=str(k,value);if(v){partial.push(quote(k)+(gap?': ':':')+v);}}}} v=partial.length===0?'{}':gap?'{\n'+gap+partial.join(',\n'+gap)+'\n'+ mind+'}':'{'+partial.join(',')+'}';gap=mind;return v;}} if(typeof JSON.stringify!=='function'){JSON.stringify=function(value,replacer,space){var i;gap='';indent='';if(typeof space==='number'){for(i=0;i<space;i+=1){indent+=' ';}}else if(typeof space==='string'){indent=space;} rep=replacer;if(replacer&&typeof replacer!=='function'&&(typeof replacer!=='object'||typeof replacer.length!=='number')){throw new Error('JSON.stringify');} return str('',{'':value});};} if(typeof JSON.parse!=='function'){JSON.parse=function(text,reviver){var j;function walk(holder,key){var k,v,value=holder[key];if(value&&typeof value==='object'){for(k in value){if(Object.hasOwnProperty.call(value,k)){v=walk(value,k);if(v!==undefined){value[k]=v;}else{delete value[k];}}}} return reviver.call(holder,key,value);} text=String(text);cx.lastIndex=0;if(cx.test(text)){text=text.replace(cx,function(a){return'\\u'+ ('0000'+a.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-4);});} if(/^[\],:{}\s]*$/.test(text.replace(/\\(?:["\\\/bfnrt]|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})/g,'@').replace(/"[^"\\\n\r]*"|true|false|null|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/g,']').replace(/(?:^|:|,)(?:\s*\[)+/g,''))){j=eval('('+text+')');return typeof reviver==='function'?walk({'':j},''):j;} throw new SyntaxError('JSON.parse');};}}());

// default response
scriptletResponse = "failure";
scriptletResult = "Tenant does not exist!";


try {
    // check to make sure scriptletInput is defined (if there was a failure, it might not be)
    if (typeof scriptletInput === "undefined"){ 
        // if scriptletInput is undefined, thow an empty exception, so the final scriptletResult will be empty
        throw "";
    }

jsObject = JSON.parse(scriptletInput);

var role = jsObject.role;
scriptletResult = roles.id[1].id;
    scriptletResponse = "success";
} 
catch (e){ 
    scriptletResult = ""+e;
}
```

===
Which throws an exception: 
ReferenceError: "roles" is not defined.

How do I get my 427afafe637e42ee87b9c7603058dc57 string from the above?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i found out how to do it:

```
// One-liner to define JSON parser and stringifier.  Minified version of http://www.json.org/json2.js
if(!this.JSON){this.JSON={};}(function(){function f(n){return n<10?'0'+n:n;} if(typeof Date.prototype.toJSON!=='function'){Date.prototype.toJSON=function(key){return isFinite(this.valueOf())?this.getUTCFullYear()+'-'+ f(this.getUTCMonth()+1)+'-'+f(this.getUTCDate())+'T'+f(this.getUTCHours())+':'+f(this.getUTCMinutes())+':'+f(this.getUTCSeconds())+'Z':null;};String.prototype.toJSON=Number.prototype.toJSON=Boolean.prototype.toJSON=function(key){return this.valueOf();};} var cx=/[\u0000\u00ad\u0600-\u0604\u070f\u17b4\u17b5\u200c-\u200f\u2028-\u202f\u2060-\u206f\ufeff\ufff0-\uffff]/g,escapable=/[\\\"\x00-\x1f\x7f-\x9f\u00ad\u0600-\u0604\u070f\u17b4\u17b5\u200c-\u200f\u2028-\u202f\u2060-\u206f\ufeff\ufff0-\uffff]/g,gap,indent,meta={'\b':'\\b','\t':'\\t','\n':'\\n','\f':'\\f','\r':'\\r','"':'\\"','\\':'\\\\'},rep;function quote(string){escapable.lastIndex=0;return escapable.test(string)?'"'+string.replace(escapable,function(a){var c=meta[a];return typeof c==='string'?c:'\\u'+('0000'+a.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-4);})+'"':'"'+string+'"';} function str(key,holder){var i,k,v,length,mind=gap,partial,value=holder[key];if(value&&typeof value==='object'&&typeof value.toJSON==='function'){value=value.toJSON(key);}if(typeof rep==='function'){value=rep.call(holder,key,value);} switch(typeof value){case'string':return quote(value);case'number':return isFinite(value)?String(value):'null';case'boolean':case'null':return String(value);case'object':if(!value){return'null';}gap+=indent;partial=[];if(Object.prototype.toString.apply(value)==='[object Array]'){length=value.length;for(i=0;i<length;i+=1){partial[i]=str(i,value)||'null';} v=partial.length===0?'[]':gap?'[\n'+gap+partial.join(',\n'+gap)+'\n'+mind+']':'['+partial.join(',')+']';gap=mind;return v;}if(rep&&typeof rep==='object'){length=rep.length;for(i=0;i<length;i+=1){k=rep[i];if(typeof k==='string'){v=str(k,value);if(v){partial.push(quote(k)+(gap?': ':':')+v);}}}}else{for(k in value){if(Object.hasOwnProperty.call(value,k)){v=str(k,value);if(v){partial.push(quote(k)+(gap?': ':':')+v);}}}} v=partial.length===0?'{}':gap?'{\n'+gap+partial.join(',\n'+gap)+'\n'+ mind+'}':'{'+partial.join(',')+'}';gap=mind;return v;}} if(typeof JSON.stringify!=='function'){JSON.stringify=function(value,replacer,space){var i;gap='';indent='';if(typeof space==='number'){for(i=0;i<space;i+=1){indent+=' ';}}else if(typeof space==='string'){indent=space;} rep=replacer;if(replacer&&typeof replacer!=='function'&&(typeof replacer!=='object'||typeof replacer.length!=='number')){throw new Error('JSON.stringify');} return str('',{'':value});};} if(typeof JSON.parse!=='function'){JSON.parse=function(text,reviver){var j;function walk(holder,key){var k,v,value=holder[key];if(value&&typeof value==='object'){for(k in value){if(Object.hasOwnProperty.call(value,k)){v=walk(value,k);if(v!==undefined){value[k]=v;}else{delete value[k];}}}} return reviver.call(holder,key,value);} text=String(text);cx.lastIndex=0;if(cx.test(text)){text=text.replace(cx,function(a){return'\\u'+ ('0000'+a.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-4);});} if(/^[\],:{}\s]*$/.test(text.replace(/\\(?:["\\\/bfnrt]|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})/g,'@').replace(/"[^"\\\n\r]*"|true|false|null|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/g,']').replace(/(?:^|:|,)(?:\s*\[)+/g,''))){j=eval('('+text+')');return typeof reviver==='function'?walk({'':j},''):j;} throw new SyntaxError('JSON.parse');};}}());

// default response
scriptletResponse = "failure";
scriptletResult = "Tenant does not exist!";


try {
    // check to make sure scriptletInput is defined (if there was a failure, it might not be)
    if (typeof scriptletInput === "undefined"){ 
        // if scriptletInput is undefined, thow an empty exception, so the final scriptletResult will be empty
        throw "";
    }

jsObject = JSON.parse(scriptletInput);

var roles = jsObject.roles;
scriptletResult = roles[1].id;
    scriptletResponse = "success";
} 
catch (e){ 
    scriptletResult = ""+e;
}
```